# Why was this spam flag declined, yet the question marked as spam?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flags, declined-flags, spam

I reviewed my flag history recently, and I noticed something curious. Now, I haven't looked into my flag history for a long time, so this flag is actually over a year old. I understand if the answer to my confusion is just going to be "There is no way to reconstruct this 13 months after the fact".

I flagged this question as spam: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63423494/2988

> ## Buy drivers license, ID cards(WhatsAp:{Contact number})passports ID cards Visa
>
> I have florida driving licenses like A123-123-12-123-1 and A123456789321.Now I am using below expression to show my data like XXXX-XXX-XX-XX1231. ([\s.,:])([a-zA-Z)\d{12}|([a-zA-Z)\d{3}[\s{1}-]\d{2}[\s{1}-]\d{3}[\s{1}-]\d{1}([\s.,:]).

And it seems the question was indeed treated as spam:

> ## This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown
>
> This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see [**the revision history**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63423494/revisions) for details.

However, I just discovered this in my flag history, regarding the spam flag I raised on that question:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Question: what is it about this question that makes it not spam? Or that at least makes it so there is additional supporting evidence needed?

Comment: I would guess a misclick; the mods have never been particularly... Erm... Positive about the UX in the mod panel.

Comment: While the question does look like spam, it wasn't actually deleted as spam. It was deleted by regular users (and a mod), and the post happened to have red flags on it at the time. When a post is actually deleted as spam, in addition to the banner you see, the post shows as deleted by the community user. So the treatment of the post was consistent with how your flag was handled at least.

Comment: @user4581301: "A post should be marked as spam […] if it promotes a product, service, or similar; and is unsolicited […]." – This user is offering fake IDs, visa, passports, and drivers licenses, which is clearly "promoting a product, service, or similar", and since nobody asked for this specific product or service, it is clearly unsolicited as well. It seems to fit the definition to me.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely spam. If it was actually intended as a question, then the title wouldn't have been *completely* spam. I can't actually answer why your flag was declined (i.e. the question you're asking here), but I suspect a mix-up somewhere. The spam flags have been marked as disputed. The post has been reported to SmokeDetector. The question has now been deleted as actual spam and the user destroyed.

Comment: This is your classic case of spam-plagiarism: they plagiarize the text of a post and add spam to it. The original, legit question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28765347/6083675.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Pulled the comment after reading the title. Question body looks like a typical junk question. Title, that's where the spam is.

Comment: Note: Given that SmokeDetector had not previously reported the question you flagged, it's likely that the title was edited during the 5 minute grace period. SmokeDetector almost certainly scanned the question within a short number of seconds after it was posted. Had that title been present, then SmokeDetector would have reported the question, but SmokeDetector did not report it. It's unclear if that (probable) grace period edit affected the handling of the post in any way other than resulting in it not being reported/detected by SmokeDetector.

Comment: @Makyen, I like the use of the term ***"destroyed"***, "deleted" would have been fine, though why stop there.   "the user destroyed, ashes distributed over the internet, do not pass go, mana and gold confiscated".

Comment: @TheGeneral Moderators have two general ways to remove a user: "delete" and "destroy". The difference is primarily what happens to the content which the user has posted on the site, with "destroy" removing all content. "Destroy" is used for spammers, trolls, and other users who are here primarily to act in violation of the Terms of Service. You can find a bit more about the difference in [What is the difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88994/271271)